# Type mismatch: inferred type is List<Any?> but List<Nothing> was expected

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have the following `Call` interface which is invariant and in another class I want to invoke one of its function, but I get the following error in this line `currentCall?.refresh(result)`.

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is List<Any?> but List<Nothing> was expected.
Projected type Call<*>? restricts use of public abstract fun refresh(list: List<T>): Unit defined in
```

I understand that with star-projection, the type becomes unknown and it's not safe to consume it. I don't know what would be the best way to change the structure and allow this operation.

What would you do in this case? How would you refresh data for instance?

```
interface Call<T> {
    fun provider(): Provider<T>
    fun items(): List<T>
    fun refresh(list: List<T>)
}

interface Provider<T> {
    fun enqueue(result: (List<T>) -> Unit)
}

class Main {

    private var currentCall: Call<*>? = null

    fun <T> add(provider: Provider<T>){}

    fun onStart() {
        currentCall?.provider()?.enqueue { result ->
            currentCall?.refresh(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have something that I don't quite understand (which may be an error). Currently it doesn't really make sense that you have `currentCall` of type `Call<*>` and a generic `add` method, because you're in no way possible to set the `provider` of the `currentCall`.

This problem can be resolved when you make `Main` generic too:

```
class Main<T> {
```

You then can safely remove the generic parameter from `add`:

```
fun add(provider: Provider<T>){}
```

And finally you can replace the star projection of `currentCall` as well with the `generic` type parameter `T`:

```
private var currentCall: Call<T>? = null
```

Which leaves you with a class like:

```
class Main<T> {

    private var currentCall: Call<T>? = null

    fun add(provider: Provider<T>){}

    fun onStart() {
        currentCall?.provider()?.enqueue { result ->
            currentCall?.refresh(result)
        }
    }
}
```

This works, because you're telling the compiler explicitly that every type you're using in `Main` **must** be somewhat related to `T`.

Comment: Indirectly I'm able to set and use it. I can't have a generic Main, that would prevent to have multiple different providers with different types.